# Why final can be initialized in constructor?

Tags: java, object, constructor, final, compile-time

I read 2 things

1. `final` should be intialized during declaration
2. Else it will be considered as `blank final variable` which should be assigned at last line in constructor

Otherwise, you will get `CTE`.

My question is,

> Why Java allows to assign/initialize value of final in constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because each instance can have it's own `final` value for it. And that can be done only through constructor because you can call constructor only once. If you want to make sure that the block gets executed only once and that too while creating the instance, constructor is the only place.

If you hard code in the class (*initialising while declaring*), that will be same for all the instances and almost become static.

Comment: Answer Accepted. Good to have few more lines of description

Comment: Not tried but can I make it as first line instead of last line in constructor